# Conditional probability issue

Tags: probability

Trying to do an execise where I have given this table

[image]

Find out

> A 1000 Ohm resistor that is selected came from Bin number 4

I then tried drawing a venn diagram, but it seems wrong
[image]

If these are the right values I put in the venn diagram, how do I find the intersection between them so I can answer this question

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: shouldn't it be 1000 instead of 1200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection is both A and B, ie $A\cap B$ so it should be the amount in the overlap, ie 600.

That table is setup like this:

\begin{array}{l c l c l c l  }
 & A_1 & A_2 \\
B_1 & A_1 \cap B_1 & A_2 \cap B_1 & \mbox{total of }B_1 \\
B_2 & A_1 \cap B_1 & A_2 \cap B_2 & \mbox{total of }B_2 \\
& \mbox{total of }A_1 & \mbox{total of }A_2 & \mbox{total of }S
\end{array}

Where the set A is split into 2 disjoint parts, wlog B is as well
S is the total set (sample space)

What you need is [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

P(1000 Ohms | Bin 4) for ease of typing O = 1000 Ohms , B = Bin 4

$P\left(O|B\right) = \frac{P\left(B|O\right)P\left(B\right)}{P\left(B|O\right)P\left(O\right) + P\left(B|\bar{O}\right)P\left(\bar{O}\right)}$

$P(not a)= P\left(\bar{a}\right) = 1- P(a)$